# Error Compiling C++ Blackjack Program (Missing Elements)

Tags: c++, project, blackjack

I'm doing a school project that creates a blackjack game, but unfortunately, I'm stumped at a few errors I must have made earlier on.  The errors appear on lines 165 and 173.  It states that I'm missing several elements that I cannot piece together.  Could someone help inform me of what's wrong with this program that won't compile?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <ctime>

#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int getCard()

{

return rand() % 10 + 1;

}

char readChar()

{

char c;

cin >> c;

cin.clear();

cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

return c;

}

int main()

{

//set srand to seed system clock

//to generate random number

srand((int)time(0));

char yesno = 'y';

do

{

int dealer = getCard();

int first = getCard(), second = getCard();

int total = first + second;

if (yesno == 'y' || yesno == 'Y')

{

cout << "The dealer starts with a " << dealer << endl;

cout << "Your first cards: " << first << ", " << second << endl;

cout << "Total: " << total << endl;

do

{

cout << "hit? (y/n): ";

yesno = readChar();

if (yesno == 'y' || yesno == 'Y')

{

int newCard = getCard();

total += newCard;

cout << "Card: " << newCard << endl;

cout << "Total: " << total << endl;

if (total > 21)

{

cout << "Bust" << endl;

yesno = 'n';

break;

}

else if(total == 21)

{

cout << "Blackjack" << endl;

}

else if (yesno == 'n' || yesno == 'N')

{

//Dealer must take more cards if less than 17

while (dealer < 17)

{

cout << "Dealer has a " << dealer << "..." << endl;

char c;

do {

cout << "(c to continue) ";

c = readChar();

} while (c != 'c' && c != 'C');

int newDealerCard = getCard();

cout << "Dealer gets a " << newDealerCard << endl;

dealer += newDealerCard;

cout << "Total: " << dealer << endl;

}

//determine winner

if (dealer == 21 && dealer != total)

cout << "Lose" << endl;

else if (dealer == total)

cout << "Push" << endl;

else if (dealer > 21 && total > dealer && total < 21)

cout << "Win" << endl;

else if (dealer > total && dealer <= 21)

cout << "Lose" << endl;

break;

}

} while (yesno != 'n' && yesno != 'N');

}
cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n) : ";

yesno = readChar();

} while (yesno != 'n' && yesno != 'N');

return 0;
}
```

Since I was a bit lost at the end, I wasn't sure where to add my missing elements.

Comment: Your curly braces don't match; they diff by one, so either one is missing or one is too much. Try to [format the code](https://godbolt.org/z/ro5MGxoeE); it makes reasoning easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two `do {...} while (...)` loops in there that do not have `while` clauses.